# Performance of .Include in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Which one is more efficient considering speed?

This one:

```
var studentWithBatchName = 
      db.Student.AsNoTracking()
        .Include(c => c.Department)
        .Include(c => c.Department.Section)
        .Include(c => c.Department.Section.Batch)
        .Select(c => c.Name, c.Department.Section.Batch.Name);
```

or this one:

```
var studentWithBatchName = 
      db.Student.AsNoTracking()
        .Include(c => c.Department.Section.Batch)
        .Select(c => c.Name, c.Department.Section.Batch.Name);
```

Comment: Please put some more effort in you question. Like Markup. Also this is a rhetorical question. You're able to measure it.

Comment: @J.vanLangen I just submitted an edit regarding the formatting.

Comment: There will be no difference as the lambada you pass in is an expression tree and not a delegate. That said, it will be converted into a SQL statement rather than being compiled and invoked right away.

Comment: EF and linq to SQL both generate SQL sentences that retrieve data that is converted into classes. Your question is unclear, you need database speed? You are worried in the classes serialization? Different queries could benefit (database speed) from table indexes and statistics. I would suggest you to use a profiler to see the actual query executed in both cases, and check its speed.

Comment: Just measure it and you have your answer, nobody else here can do that.

Comment: `.Select(c => c.Name, c.Department.Section.Batch.Name)` is not a valid C# construct. But assuming it is a normal projection method `Select(c => new { … }`, there is no difference because `Include`s are simply ignored in projection queries.

Answer (score 1):

The Include statement is just getting the data from the related datasources/tables. If you are saying Include(c => c.Department.Section.Batch) you get the .Department.Section.Batch values.

If you are using .Include(c => c.Department).Include(c => c.Department.Section).Include(c => c.Department.Section.Batch)
it would theoretically add 3 joins to the query. I don't know if .NET catches these circumstances, but I would consider using ONLY Include(c => c.Department.Section.Batch) when you only need this value.

Comment: I'd guess even in the single .Include will need three joins too? Assuming the Student record only has a DepartmentId and not a BatchId directly, so you'll still have to go through the department to find the batch.

Answer (score 1):

Found .ProjectTo to be more efficient considering speed. Instead of using Include which acts like outer join and makes your query big putting load on the server one can use .ProjectTo<>

Can get .ProjectTo<> by
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;

Eg. var response = await db.TableName.ProjectTo().ToListAsync();